# amqp callback confirm: true not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm new to NodeJS and we are using amqp 0.2.6.  I have psuedocode that looks like

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
         // do logic and pass parameters to next method by calling callback
    },

    function(params, callback) {
         // do AMQP logic and pass parameters to next method
            try {       
          bus.publish(routingKey, message, options, function (err) {
                 console.log("got here");
                 if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                 }
          });
        //callback(null, null);    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
        //callback(err, null);
    }


    }
], function() {
        // do logic with all results
});
```

So I have a couple questions.  First, is there something wrong with my callback when I call publish?  My message gets sent to the Rabbit properly but I never get to the callback `got here` message.

If I uncomment the two lines that start with callback, then my second function in async.waterfall gets its callback right away and then calls its callback to pass the results to the final function in async.waterfall.   I do understand that this is happening since the callback gets called right after publish.  What I'd like to do is ideally call the callback after I know if my message sent to rabbit succeeds with no error or with an error.  I don't know how I would do this since I cannot get to the callback of the amqp publish message.  I do see in my try/catch block if there is an error, I see my error logged, but this is after my async.waterfall function has already finished.  I'd like to pass the results of my publish message (success or failure) to the second function in async.waterfall.  Any non-blocking way I can achieve this is fine.  So in the end the goal is

```
async.waterfall([
    function (one) {
         // do logic and pass results to 'two'
    }, 
    function (two) {
         // do AMQP logic, send a message, get the results of that action and pass to last function
    }
], function() {
        // i got my results from 'one' and 'two', do some more logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the waterfall callback as your `bus.publish()` callback. This will invoke that callback whenever `bus.publish()` is finished, and your final function in `async.waterfall()` will have an error (if an error is passed) and/or a result from bus.publish().

An example of your code updated might look something like this, but you can adjust it to meet your needs.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
         // do logic and pass parameters to next method by calling callback
         callback(null, params)
    },

    function(params, callback) {
         // do AMQP logic and pass parameters to next method    
         bus.publish(routingKey, message, options, callback)
    }
], function(err, result) {
        // err:    if an error is thrown and passed into the callback for bus.publish(), should be set here, otherwise should be `null` 
        // result: if bus.publish() gives you a result in the callback after it publishes the message, would be here
})
```

Comment: Ya that doesn't work because like I mentioned, the callback in publish() is not getting called for some reason.

Comment: okay, then that's a problem with the specific publish method then. can you provide the code for the publish method, or are you using a specific library? If it's a library and you're confident you've provided the arguments to the method that it needs to work as expected, you should probably open an issue with the maintainer since you're issue isn't with the async library or with the pattern you're using. even still, you should make sure you call callback within the publish method to ensure you're catching errors there.

Comment: Looking at the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp#exchangepublishroutingkey-message-options-callback) it looks like callback only gets called if the exchange is in "confirm mode". have you confirmed it is?

Comment: I did set that attribute and in my code check that `confirm` property on the exchange is set to true.  So i'm really not sure why that callback doesn't get called.